# Can an app read / access API calls of other Android App?

Tags: android, function-calls

Can anybody help me on this.
Can an app (installed) on android device read API calls of other app (installed on device)

I am developing android malware detection based on features such as permission and api calls. The first part, (reading the permission of other Android app is successful) but could not find code that enable the app to read other app API calls. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you consider to be 'an API call'?

Comment: Something like these:"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getDeviceId 
"
"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getDeviceSoftwareVersion 
"
"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getLine1Number 
"
"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getSimSerialNumber 
"
"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getSubscriberId 
"
"android/telephony/TelephonyManager;->getVoiceMailNumber 
"
"Cipher(AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding) 
"